# prepend table row with slide down

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jquery to prepend an existing row, making it appear with a sliding down effect. It works, except for the slide down effect. What could be causing this problem?

```
$('#sales_slider .sales_slider_row:last').hide().prependTo('#sales_slider').slideDown();
```

I mean, it appears at the top as it should be, like shuffling cards, it just doesn't play the effect.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it? it would be very helpful.

Comment: trying to write a jsfiddle for it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1e4tbmvg/ This jsfiddle doesn't do anything but in my actual code it does prepend them correctly. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question didn't elaborate very well, try the following:

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody id="sales_slider">
        <tr class="sales_slider_row">
            <td>test 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sales_slider_row">
            <td>test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sales_slider_row">
            <td>test 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#sales_slider .sales_slider_row:last').prependTo('#sales_slider').hide().fadeIn();
    },4000);
});
```

The animation is working as you can see with css: http://jsfiddle.net/1e4tbmvg/2/

Comment: Sorry I was just making a jsfiddle.net/1e4tbmvg ...This jsfiddle doesn't do anything but in my actual code it does prepend them correctly. Weird.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/1e4tbmvg/1/ - The effect would look a lot better with fadeIn() in my opinion though :)

Comment: Ah good point and thanks, I think I will bow to your artistic opinion and go with fadeIn() :)

Comment: FYI, The reason your fiddle wasn't doing anything was because you needed to select jQuery from the select box on the left - Glad it's sorted.